# I want to set a trigger in GTM when a message appears on site

Tags: google-tag-manager

I believe I should be able to set a trigger within Google Tag Manager, for when a confirmation message appears on a page.

This is because when someone submits the form, it doesn't go to a thank you page. The page URL remains the same, but a thank you message appears.

My understanding is that I can just wrap that message with an element ID, and then use this as a trigger in GTM.

If anyone can confirm this, or has any experience as to the best way to do this, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you please your HTML or provide link to your website with form

Comment: Can you post the code snippet you have used to trigger this behaviour.How exactly have you configured GTM for the message triggering?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. First you have to enable "Form ID" which is GTM's Built-In Variable:

1. Go to Varaibles
2. Under "Built-In Variables" click "CONFIGURE"
3. Scroll to "Forms" section and enable Form ID

[image]

Now you can setup trigger on form submission:

1. Go to Triggers
2. Click on "New"
3. Click on "Trigger Configuration"
4. Under "Other" select "Form Submission"
5. Now you can select "Some Forms" and set the Trigger as: "Form ID - equals - your ID"

[image]